# how to diplay two tables properties in a single view in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have three tabs as shown in image each tab loads different content from respective table, student tab loads student details from student table, Details tab loads contact details from contact table and Marks tab loads student marks from marks.All three tables are having common property as id, which is unique.How to display student name when clicked on details tab and marks tab 
Note:Student name is present only in student table.

```
@model IEnumerable<SA.Models.Detail>
```

Using this I'm able to load only detail table properties, how can i get the properties from student  table in detail view, so that i can display student name

[image]

[image]

Comment: -1: just for the stupid tag-spam

Answer (score 1):

Create a view model class that holds both tables.

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public List<string> List1;
    public List<string> List2;
    ...
}

...

@model SA.Models.SomeViewModel
...
@Model.List1
...
```

If the lists are similar you could create a partial view where you render them.

Comment: I did the same why as u suggested,In view while displaying using foreach(var item in model){@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem = > Item.List!1); @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>Item.List2)}   I'm getting an error like this: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SA.Models.Detail]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SA.Models.NewModel]'.

Comment: Not sure what you've done exactly, but you seem to try inserting the view model into the an enumerable model. You are supposed to change your current view model into the new one (not as an enumerable) and use that model in your controller to place you data. But I'm not sure what you've done at the moment, post your code and I can help out :)

Comment: That look correct, so in your view, are you using @model SA.Models.SomeViewModel? Looking at your error they don't really seem to match up with what's sent from the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Use following Foreach in your view.

```
@foreach(var item in Model.List1)
```